# 2002 chevy 1500 4.3l v6 cfsi fuel to fuel rail but not to cylinders

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-injection, silverado

I own a 2002 chevy 1500 4.3l v6 cfsi, fuel to schrader valve on rail, none in cylinders.Could it be clogged injectors?

Comment: I have spark, it will e

Comment: No fuel flow through _any_ of the injectors? It's possible that all the injectors are plugged and inoperative, perhaps because the engine sat unused for a long time. But it's much more likely that, with no injector passing fuel, the cause is an electrical fault in the circuit or wiring that controls the injectors' opening and closing. Find or buy a known-good injector, and put it in place. If that injector doesn't pass fuel, the engine has an electrical fault. If that injector does pass fuel, then the other injectors are likely plugged and should be cleaned, rebuilt, or replaced.

Comment: I'd check to see if the injectors are firing before I'd think ALL of the injectors are plugged.

Comment: Do you own any electrical test equipment?